# Welche Bedeutungen eines Wortes verwendbar sind — Resourcen

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary, resource, dictionary

Ich lerne Deutsch seit knapp 4 Jahren. Vor einigen Monaten habe ich angefangen, deutsche Wörter nicht nur in ihrer Hauptbedeutung, sondern auch in denen aufzuschreiben, die weniger verwendbar sind. Dabei habe ich immer Duden und DWDS benutzt sowie andere kleinere Wörterbücher. Zu meiner letzten Frage hier, wo ich über das Wort "ankommen" in der Bedeutung "ergreifen, überkommen" geredet habe, haben Leute geschrieben, dass man es in dieser Bedeutung schon gar nicht gebraucht (obwohl sie auf Duden und DWDS bloß als gehoben bezeichnet ist). Das hat mich veranlasst nachzudenken, wie ich herausfinden kann, welche Bedeutungen eines Wortes heutzutage tatsächlich verwendet werden und welche nicht. Aus solchen Sites kenne ich nur context.reverso.net, und daraus kann man leider überhaupt nicht immer schlussfolgern. Vielleicht kennt ihr noch etwas Hilfsreiches?

Comment: The best way: read current texts of whatever genre, listen current podcasts, news audio books or whatever media, talk to people. But this advice is probably only moderately helpful, thus not as an anser :)

Comment: In diesem Fall würde ich sagen, die Information im Duden ist falsch. Diese Bedeutung ist nicht gehoben, sondern veraltet.

Answer (score 1):

Es sind eigentlich ja gerade Wörterbücher, in denen man diese Art von Informationen nachschlagen können sollte. Wenn man also Fragen zum Wortgebrauch hat, die so speziell sind, dass selbst mehrere Wörterbücher sie nicht richtig beantworten, wird es schwierig, Alternativen zu finden. Man kann natürlich einen Muttersprachler fragen, zum Beispiel auf dieser Website.

Ich verwende https://www.linguee.de und die DWDS Korpora, um viele Beispiele für die Verwendung eines bestimmten Wortes oder einer bestimmten Wortkombination zu finden, manchmal auch nur Google-Suchen, aber das in der Frage angegebene Beispiel wird dort schwer zu finden sein. Solche Datenbanken sind generell nur begrenzt hilfreich beim Versuch, eine negative Aussage zu belegen wie die, dass eine Formulierung nicht mehr genutzt wird.

Die Verwendung einer Wortkombination über die Jahre kann mit [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/lexdb) oder [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) recherchiert werden.

---

English:

I'm afraid it's dictionaries that are supposed to be the source for  this kind of knowledge. So if you have questions about word usage that are so special that even several dictionaries don't get them right, it will be hard to find alternatives. You can ask a native speaker of course, like on this site.

I use https://www.linguee.de and the DWDS Korpora to find lots of examples for a given word or word combination, sometimes also just Google searches, but the example you gave will be hard for search for,  and sources like that are of limited help when trying to prove a negative.

Use of a word combination over time can be researched with [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/lexdb) or [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/).